# Loading a pre-compiled class using the JavaCompiler API

Tags: java, caching, compiler-construction, classpath

I am using an In Memory Java Compiler that takes Java source code and produes instantiable `Class` Objects.

Now I enhanced the compiler by a Cache that caches the byte code produced by the compiler for a class's source code.

As a result of this, I can no longer compile classes that are dependent on a class from the Cache, i.e., if class **A** (dependent on **B**) and **B** get compiled, they both get cached. If I then change **A**, only **A** gets recompiled, and I get an error about **B** not being found:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: class MyClass
```

How can I fix this? Is the `ClassLoader` or the `FileManager` responsible for resolving dependencies the `JavaCompiler` encounters during the compilation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I got it working by extending the `FileManager`'s `list()` method to return an `Iterable` of my `JavaFileObject`s. Works like a charm!